# Efficient ExpandableListView implementation for Flutter

Tags: dart, expandablelistview, flutter

I'm trying to implement an ExpandableListView similar to this on Android https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

I was able to implement something similar using the Catalog Flutter example https://flutter.io/catalog/samples/ where I add and remove an entire Column on tap. However, for a size bigger than 50, it starts being inefficient and takes quite a lot of time to load. Can you suggest a better and more efficient approach in implementing something similar?

Answer (score 3):

[`ExpansionTile`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html) can be used to produce two-level or multi-level lists. If they are used as they are in the [expansion tile sample](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/catalog/lib/expansion_tile_sample.dart), they should efficient. The important thing is to use [`ListView.builder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) since the default `ListView` constructor is not optimized for large amounts of content.

If you're still not getting the performance you want after trying this, please post a code sample in your question and we can suggest how to improve it.